How to start a Django Celery Shared task using redis-cli
i have a Celery task defined in django application as below
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def save_notification(notification):
    print("Received notif", notification)

for testing purpose in django container i type following command to start celery worker
celery -A hello_django worker --loglevel=INFO

it starts as expected and tasks is discovered, now the important thing i need to start the task using some arguments. So for testing i am using below command.
redis-cli -n 0 RPUSH celery "{\"task\":\"notifications.tasks.save_notification\", \"args\":[\"I am notification\"]}"

Commands publishes successfully and print some integer but on worker side it crashes and following error occurs
[2024-05-13 13:03:55,610: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: KeyError('properties')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 340, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 742, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 97, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 373, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1344, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 569, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 974, in _brpop_read
    self.connection._deliver(loads(bytes_to_str(item)), dest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 1017, in _deliver
    callback(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 636, in _callback
    message = self.Message(raw_message, channel=self)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 323, in __init__
    properties = payload['properties']
                 ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'properties'

I know it complains about properties key but i tried to add one it further requires more attributes in properties i don't know the exact format of message, how can i call the task without any error?
